# How do I connect wxWidgets, GTK2 widgets, and X11 windows?

Tags: c++, linux, gtk, wxwidgets, x11

I gather from the various wxWidgets class references in the documentation ([example](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/classwx_web_view.html)) that the wxWidgets used to build a GUI basically inherit from `wxWindow`. I see from the comments in [the source of wxWidgets/window.cpp](https://github.com/wxWidgets/wxWidgets/blob/master/src/gtk/window.cpp) that each `wxWindow` has  a pointer to some GtkWidget which is stored in the `m_widget` member of the wxWidget object. From the same source code comments I also see that `m_wxwindow` is a member of the `wxWindow` class, and may hold a pointer to a `wxPizza` object in the case of a `wxWindow` that has a client area for drawing and children.

I am working on an application that requires this sort of functionality. I am extending a wxWidgets class to create my own widget, which needs to contain a drawable X11 window, and I'm not really sure how to connect it all up and I'm having trouble finding a solution using the documentation.

When I am creating my custom widget (in the `Create` method), I can see that `m_widget` and `m_wxwindow` are both `NULL`, so from this and what I mentioned above, I gather these are the `GtkWidget` objects that I should be creating to form my client area. First, I tried this:

```
m_widget = gtk_window_new(GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);
```

Which kind of works but not quite like I want it to. I'm able to get the `XID` from the `GtkWidget` and the X11 window behaves as expected. But this creates a new window outside of my main wxWidgets app window. What I want is this exact functionality except embedded inside my main wxWidgets app window. My custom class has been added to a `wxBoxSizer` like this:

```
sizer->Add(my_widget, 1, wxEXPAND | wxALL, 0);
```

Where sizer is a `wxBoxSizer` and `my_widget` is my custom widget.

I then tried creating `m_widget` as a few different types of `GtkWidget` but these all resulted in run-time errors when trying to use `gtk_widget_realize` and trying to get the `XID`.

```
// These don't work
m_widget = gtk_drawing_area_new();
m_widget = gtk_vbox_new(false, 0);
```

These are the error messages I'm getting when I tried the above:

```
Gtk: IA__gtk_widget_realize: assertion 'GTK_WIDGET_ANCHORED (widget) || GTK_IS_INVISIBLE (widget)' failed
Gdk: gdkdrawable-x11.c:952 drawable is not a pixmap or window
Check failed: xwindow.
```

So I this is a multi-part question:

- What is an appropriate `GtkWidget` type to get this accomplished? I need to be able to obtain a drawable X11 window ID (`XID`) and to embed it within the parent widget (`wxBoxSizer`).
- Do I need to use both `m_widget` and `m_wxwindow`? How do I set these up?
- Do I need to do anything other than call `sizer->Add()` in order to connect this up with my `wxBoxSizer`?

Thanks!

**UPDATE:** Sorry I forgot to mention, this is for GTK2. Thanks @andlabs for pointing this out.

**UPDATE 2:** @VZ. recommended that I clarify what I'm trying to do.

I'm using a library that needs access to an X11 window, but does not create that window itself. When I initialize the library, I need to pass it an X11 window handle (`XID`). The library will then draw into that window. I want to create this window to be inside my wxWidgets application. I'm trying to extend a wxWidgets class so that I will be able to add these X11 windows to widgets based on `wxSizer` in my application.

I know that `gtk_window_new()` is not what I'm looking for because it creates a new top-level window, while I want a window embedded in my wxWidgets application. It's just something I tried along the way.

Comment: @David, why do you care? All this m_widget and m_wxwindow are exclusively wxWidgets internal. Did you try the drawing sample of wxWidgets? Or any other samples for that matter?

Comment: Thanks for asking @andlabs, it's GTK+ 2

Comment: Are you referring to the basic wxWidgets sample applications @Igor? I can build and run these applications but I'm trying to create my own wxWidgets widget that extends an existing wxWidgets class. I need the XID of a drawable X11 window within my widget because another library that I'm trying to use requires it. If there's anything specific that requires clarification I'd be happy to provide more information. Or if there's a sample that covers my use case that would be awesome too, but I wasn't able to find one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be really helpful to know what exactly are you trying to do. You speak about `GtkWidgets`s but then show `gtk_window_new()` call which creates a new (top level) window, which is something quite different and can only be represented by `wxTopLevelWindow` at wx level.

Do you need to wrap an existing `GtkWidget` in a wxWidgets application? If so, you should just use [wxNativeWindow](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/classwx_native_window.html). Even if you don't use the latest version with it, you can still easily reuse/duplicate its code.

Do you need to wrap an existing `XWindow`? Then it's more difficult because you can't easily do it with wxGTK. You could use wxX11, but this port is not in a good state, so it's probably not the best idea, unless your needs are very limited. The best would probably be to wrap X window in a `GtkWidget` first and then proceed as above.

---

After the update, it seems that you just need a XID of an existing window. This is even simpler than embedding a GTK+ widget as you can get the `GtkWidget` using `wxWindow::GetHandle()`, then use `gtk_widget_get_window()` to get its `GdkWindow` and finally use `GDK_WINDOW_XID()` to get the XID.

Comment: Thanks @VZ. I've updated my question to clarify what I'm looking for. I want to wrap an X11 window in a wxWidgets widget, but it's not an existing X11 window - I want to create one that I will then use later.

Comment: Marking as the answer because I will be going down the path of trying to embed an X11 window in a GtkWidget, and then embedding the GtkWidget in the wxWidgets application. Thanks @VZ.!